# use an in memory collection in dotnet core - how to make available to all classes

Tags: caching, .net-core, singleton, in-memory-database, in-memory

IN dotnet core project, how do you make a collection available in memory to any class at any given time?
I was thinking of the following approach:

```
public interface IInMemoryCache
{
    public void Setup();
}

public class InMemoryCache : IInMemoryCache
{
    private List<MyObject> cache;
    public void Setup() // entered once when app is started 
    {
        cache = new List<MyObject>() { 
                new MyObject("param1", "param2"), 
                new MyObject("param3", "param4") 
    } 
    public IList<MyObject> GetCollection() 
    {
        return this.collection;
    }
}
```

and then in Startup:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IInMemoryCache cache)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    cache.Setup();
```

etc

and also:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) { 
    services.AddSingleton<IInMemoryCache, InMemoryCache>();
```

Is this a good approach, does it mean I can inject IInMemoryCache in any class and able to access the cache object? - for the whole lifetime of the app (meaning, while it's up and running, if I restart it, the collection is expected to again initialise from running the Setup method)

So right now in any class I just add: `IInMemoryCache cache`
and then `cache.GetCollection()` to retrieve the collection (that was setup ONCE at app startup).

is there a better way like a native feature for caching a collection available to all classes?

Comment: I would say that this is a fine approach. However, you should consider thread-safety when exposing a `List<T>` the way you do. By returning the collection you expose yourself to threading issues. Consider using an `ImmutableList` and then with Add/Remove-methods in your `IMemoryCache` which handles thread safety. Otherwise I would say it's fine.

Comment: Also, you could take a look at `IStartupFilter`. It's a nice way to add your custom startup behavior to your application, which removes the dependency to `IInMemoryCache` in Startup.cs - https://andrewlock.net/exploring-istartupfilter-in-asp-net-core/